# How to convert a instance of CKEDITOR.dom.element into a jquery object in CKEDITOR?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have a UI element which is an instance of CKEDITOR.dom.element.I can use methods like getId() on it to find it's id in the native DOM.But how can I convert into a jquery object to apply advanced jquery methods on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.domObject-property-S-) property to access the native DOM element

```
var native = document.createElement( 'div' );
var cke = new CKEDITOR.dom.element( native );
var jq = $( cke.$ );
```

`jq` is a jQuery element set.

Comment: how to do the reverse?